# Select columns of multiple items in SQL on Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have something like that :

- product 1 with rating rating2 rating3 etc... in my database
- product 3 with rating rationg2 ratioN3 etc... in my database

My wish is to select all notations (given by members) to make the average rating.

I looked in the collections helpers but I don't found what I am looking for.

My goal is to make something generic, like an helper per example, but Im open to all method you can suggest to help me to do this.

One more difficulty is that Im showing all the products on the same page....

Bests

Comment: Can you please share the DB structure and output structure?

Comment: I have a table called "product" and I have "product_carac_rating1", "product_carac_rating2" etc... and and the same page I show all the product and foreach I would like to make the average rating

Answer (score 3):

In your **Product** model you must have a relation with rating model (one to many).

In **Rating** model you have a belongsTo realtion with Product and in ratings table a field **product_id**.

so in **Product** model have a rating getter that calculates the rating of each product.

`Product.php`

```php
    public function ratings(){
        return $this->hasMany(Rating::class, 'product_id');
    }
```

`Rating.php`

```php
    public function product(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'product_id');
    }
```

Now you can have the rattings getter in productmodel

`Product.php`

```php
    public function getRatingAttribute(){
    
        $sum = 0;
        $ratings = $this->ratings->each(function($rating) use ($sum){
            $sum += $rating->score;
        });
        return round($sum / count($this->ratings));
    }
```

I have not tested this but it should work.If you want to use the rating for other stuff like comments then you should use **morphMany** instead of **hasMany**  and use the polymorphic relation.

This is the [link](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations) for laravel documentation with a good example and [this](https://hdtuto.com/article/php-laravel-5-rating-system-example-from-scratch) is a tutorial on how to implement .

Good luck ;) and don't forget to put **user_id** on rating record as well and put a unique constraint on *user_id* and *product_id* so each user can rate a product only once.

Comment: Thanks for that, really its cool. But its not my database structure because of I explain it badly. Its not so many ratings by members but juste 5 ou 6 because I write de rates myself so I dont need ton make some differents tables. But thank you again

Comment: this is the common way of implementing rating for Laravel, and I didn't understand what does writing the rating yourself mean.
if you have some special table that has the rating records in it, you can use the DB to gain access to that table data and perform what you want